# calling angular page inside aspx page

Tags: asp.net, angular

I have build a sample angular 7 application and serve on port 4200. localhost:4200/contact working fine.

I have an existing asp.net web form application. I want to call angular contact page via some button on Home.aspx and vise versa.

One way: I have to use absolute path of angular app inside aspx page.

Second way: I have build the angular app inside asp.net web application under dist folder. In such case, how can i call the contact page on home.aspx page.
Example

`href ="/angularapp/dist/contact`  is not working

`href ="/home2.aspx` is working

The screenshot of the generated index.html file is 
[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiFY8.png)

Please advise

The purpose of this is to mix use of aspx pages and angular pages

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that from the webserver point of view there is no resource at /angularapp/dist/contact, so it returns a 404.

What you can do is to add routing to your webforms app like described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/url-routing).

You have to define a catch all route for your /angularapp/dist/ section. Something like this

```
routes.MapPageRoute("defaultRoute", "angularapp/dist/{*value}", "~/Angular.aspx");
```

Then, create a file called Angular.aspx and replace its content with the contents of your index.html file.

This will lead to the following flow:

1. Client requests angularapp/dist/contact
2. Server matches your catch all route to that request and runs Angular.aspx
3. Angular.aspx returns the content of your index.html file
4. Angular routing kicks in and runs your contact component

If this doesn't work for you and you just get a blank screen, make sure to open the browsers devtools and look for any errors. It might be that you have to adjust your base href value or the links to your scripts.

Comment: Thank you Andre. Past the index.html with some path correction in newly created page (angular.aspx).  It now displays the main page of my angular app with base path as url. However it still not redirect to the contact or any other page directly.

Comment: I have used the call as /webapp/angular.aspx but need to call to achieve like  /angular.aspx/contact

Comment: just make sure that you don't link to /webapp/angular.aspx. Because this will cause issues with client side angular routing. Just link to /angularapp/dist/contact and make sure that you have the asp.net webforms routing confgured